# Deformations of a CFT and UV completion

Tags: renormalization, conformal-field-theory

Take the space of all effective quantum field theories. There is only a small subset of this space of effective quantum field theories which are UV complete.

My question s very simple. It is the following:

**Do all UV complete QFTs have a fixed point in the UV?**

I ask this question, because I want to understand the difference between relevant, irrelevant and marginal deformations of a CFT into a QFT. As far as I understand, relevant and marginal deformations of a CFT preserve the UV fixed point, whilst irrelevant deformations of a CFT spoil the UV fixed point.

**What does it mean to preserve or spoil a UV fixed point?**

Comment: 1. How are you defining "UV complete theory" that it is not by definition the same as "has a UV fixed point"? 2. I don't understand what is unclear about the words "preserve" or "spoil" here. Do you still not understand the statement when one replaces them by the less flowery "not change" and "change"?

Comment: 2. To me, it appears that, any deformation of a CFT should not change the UV fixed point. I do not see why irrelevant deformations of a CFT change the UV fixed point.

Comment: You can watch Dumitrescu's talk at Strings 2017 for a global picture of the RG flow